# Bootstrap DatePicker Set Default Date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to set the default date for the datepicker but it does not work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker input').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "top auto",
        todayHighlight: true,
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
        setDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

This is the result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript date object is not compatible with Twitter bootstrap datepicker format.

You will need to create the default date step by step. Now this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 var today = new Date();
 var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //Month starts from 0
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

 if(mm<10){
     mm='0'+mm
 } 
 today = mm+'-'+yyyy;

 $('.datepicker input').val(today);

 $('.datepicker input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "top auto",
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months",
    minViewMode: "months"
 });
});
```

UPDATE: Added `today` value to input first

Comment: thanks @mvpasarel I tried to implement it and It still returned the date as in the image.

Comment: Can you console.log(today) and give me the output?

Comment: What version/package of boostrap-datepicker are you using? I tried this on http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker and worked:

   <input class="datepicker" type="text" value="01-2015">

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        minViewMode: 1
    });

Comment: It didn't give me any output. Weird. I'm using it in a PartialView that displays in a BootStrap modal form.

Comment: You should try adding the `today` value directly to input first, and then trigger datepicker. Hope that works. I have tested on eternicode demo site and seems to be fine.

Comment: Thanks, It worked if I set the date first. The console did output a value if I loaded the correct form ;)